# Simple libcurl async callback demo?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, libcurl

I am using libcurl to do rest request. I want to make it async, the ideal code is like this:

```
size_t curl_cb(void *content, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* ptr) {  // this is callback
  std::string* buf = (std::string*)ptr;
  buf->append((char*)content, size * nmemb);
  return size * nmemb;
}
int main() {
  CURL* curl_ = curl_somekind_init();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // set url, callback for curl_
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_, CALLBACK, curl_cb);
    curl_somekind_perform(curl); // assume this will cost 3s to get response if sync
  }
  while (1);
}
```

I want the for loop can send url request fast, not block by the previous curl network latency. this is all i want

I know there are many questions about this, and the most use `curl_multi`, i am very confused, because it bring a lot of other things which confused me, could you help on this with a tiny demo?

Comment: You should start here: [curl_multi_perform](https://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_multi_perform)